# When is the best time to request type data in a SPA?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, durandal

We have a large SPA application with many edit dialogs for various models. Each edit dialog can contain up to 8 drop downs containing options for things like gender, ethnicity, state, etc.

When the user lands on a section of the application where they can make an edit, I currently make http requests  for all of these dropdown options, as the options are maintained by admin users and may change frequently.  This way if the user chooses to edit, there is no delay as the options were silently loaded in anticipation of an edit. When I receive the options, they are cached in local storage for an hour.

I was recently asked if we could not request the options until an edit is actually initiated as it was creating wasteful network traffic. Now there is a solid 1 second delay from when the edit button is clicked until the options are received and the dialog opens.

My question is - what is best practice for when and how to load this kind of data? I could add a loading message to the dialog, but part of me feels like the requests are so small...why not load the data as soon as we can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best would be to load all data during the bootstrap with caching in the localstorage plus setting up polling or websockets to update your data as soon as it changes on server. That would result in minimal traffic and no delays in the UI.